# Why is open('MyDocumentation.pptx') in Matlab not working as expected?

Tags: matlab

Within the callback-fcn of a button, I want to open a pptx-file with the

> appropriate application

as mentioned in the doc of the open-fcn. What in this case, would mean, that it opens the file with M$ powerpoint...

What I do:

```
function pushbutton_opendoc_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    open('MyDocumentation.pptx')
end
```

What I get:

It opens the .pptx-file with the matlab-editor :o

As far as I can remember, the last time I was using this function, it was working perfectly fine.

My question:
What is or what could be wrong-> perhaps there are some settings, I changed by accident? I couldnt find out something about that...

btw.: I'm using Matlab R2013a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need `winopen` rather than `open`.

Comment: Indeed, this is working fine. Still, I'm pretty sure, that it was working fine just a few days before. I'll check what could have changed, perhaps I was using another version of Matlab... Thanks a lot!